# What are the methods for gaining Bezels in battle?

Tags: resonance-of-fate

From what I understand, you gain Bezels from killing enemies and shooting off parts, but when I performed a Heroic Action while fighting a bunch of Fat Gangsters (basic jump over them during my run doing direct), I didn't kill any, but regained a Bezel.

When I did it again, (same action but doing scrap damage on a different Fat Gangster), I didn't gain any.

In both cases I didn't see any parts fall off or anything like that, nor did they become airborne (as I was shooting from above).

What are all the methods of regaining lost/spent Bezels?

Comment: God, I loved that game.

Comment: @JohnoBoy - Dat [gun customization](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/757/bn84cs.jpg)

Comment: No magazine attachments on that gun? For shame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can gain bezels either by breaking off shields, killing enemies or picking up broken bezel shards during combat.

What happened is you probably took off a shield during your first action, therefore gained a bezel, your second action didn't gain you any bezels since you only did scratch damage.